# Export MS Project 2010 to MS Access .mdb file

Tags: ms-access, export, ms-project

I've written an C# application which works with .mdb exported by MS Project 2003. Now my company has upgraded to MS Project 2010 and I can't find any chance to export the whole data to an .mdb file.

Can you help me to export all data or is there an other solution. I'd be very thankful for any workaround tip!

Those are the tables I unconditionally need:
MSP_ASSIGNMENTS, MSP_CALENDAR_DATA, MSP_CALENDARS, MSP_PROJECTS, MSP_RESOURCES, MSP_TASKS

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing the code yourself to populate the database, you can achieve this using the Project SDK (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758031) or something like MPXJ (http://mpxj.sf.net). You might even be able to do it using a VBA macro from within Project itself.

Comment: I've already found a workaround: I'm exporting the project as xml and then read it with my app and rebuild an mdb database which looks like the old "export as mdb" database which I than can open. So far there is only one column missing which I couldn't rebuild - so I had to edit the original code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Project" tab, click "Visual Reports", then click the "Save Data" button (towards the bottom), then click "Save Database".